# Как создать файл для логирования

Tags: java

У меня есть программа в которой  я использую sl4j, для логов пишу log.info() . Как можно создать отдельный файл для логов в проекте?

Comment: Нужно сконфигурировать лог, в нем указав файлы, куда вы будете его писать. sl4j - это интерфейс, кинфигурация зависит от библиотеки логгирования. Если это log4j, то в log4j.properties нужно сконфигурировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

application.properties

```
 logging.file.name=fileExample.log
```

Вариант без спринга 
resources/logback.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="fileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>myLogFile.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level  %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Пример

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    public class LogbackTest {


    public static Logger slf4jLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogbackTest.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        slf4jLogger.trace("Hello World!");

        String name = "Abhijit";
        slf4jLogger.debug("Hi, {}", name);
        slf4jLogger.info("Welcome to the HelloWorld example of Logback.");
        slf4jLogger.warn("Dummy warning message.");
        slf4jLogger.error("Dummy error message.");
    }
}
```

Comment: при запуске приложения этот файл создастся ?

Comment: @АртёмКурилко да

Comment: можно ли без спринг бута его создать, у меня консольное приложение

Comment: @АртёмКурилко обновил ответ